# Can we automate signing request of CSR generated by ACM?

Tags: certificate, csr, aws-certificate-manager

Using AWS ACM Cert authority, I have created a CSR for subordinate CA following this [step](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm-pca/latest/userguide/PcaGetCsr.html).

---

I further need to sign the CSR(as mentioned below):

### [image]

Currently we do not have any infrastructure to sign the CSR using root CA's private key. We currently have root CA from Entrust.

Goal is to automate this signing request using [acm sdk](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/acm/)

How to proceed further on signing the CSR with this root CA's private key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I strongly advise you to get someone who understands PKI to set up an internal certificate authority for you.

You can sign a CSR using openssl. Here is an example command.

```
openssl ca -config intermediate/openssl.cnf \
      -extensions server_cert -days 375 -notext -md sha256 \
      -in intermediate/csr/www.example.com.csr.pem \
      -out intermediate/certs/www.example.com.cert.pem
```

Here is a link to an example openssl.cnf:

http://web.mit.edu/crypto/openssl.cnf

Comment: Can you also comment on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56692983/how-to-create-client-device-certificates