# AWS Cert Mgr - How to create client & device certificates?

Tags: go, certificate, client-certificates, aws-certificate-manager

From [AWS tech talk](https://youtu.be/nDDBcP-iiSs?t=280), I have learnt that,

### [image]

I am able to create private server certificate using below option:

[image]

### -------------------

The server certificates serve the rationale of encrypting and decrypting the content.

Whereas

client certificate as the name implies is clearly used to identify a client to a respective user

A device certificate creates an identity for each “thing” in an IoT ecosystem, 
making sure each device authenticates as it connects, and protects communication between devices.

---

We have created root CA and subordinate CA using AWS Cert mgr through console.

How to create device & client certificate(private) using ACM GoLang sdk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[UPDATE after question asked for ACM]

Use the `aws acm-pca issue-certificate` command to request a certificate:

```
CLIENT_ID="device-0001"
CLIENT_SERIAL=0001

# Create the CSR and Private Key
openssl req -new -newkey rsa:2048 -days 365 -keyout ${CLIENT_ID}.key -out ${CLIENT_ID}.csr

# Replace --certificate-authority-arn with your ARN returned when you create the certificate authority.

aws acm-pca issue-certificate \
--csr file://${CLIENT_ID}.csr \
--signing-algorithm "SHA256WITHRSA" \
--validity Value=375,Type="DAYS" \
--idempotency-token 12983 \
--certificate-authority-arn arn:aws:acm-pca:region:account:\
certificate-authority/12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789012
```

This command outputs the ARN, save this value for the next command ($MY-CERT-ARN)

```
aws acm-pca get-certificate \
--certificate-authority-arn arn:aws:acm-pca:region:account:\
certificate-authority/12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789012 \
--certificate-arn $MY-CERT-ARN \
 --output text > ${CLIENT_ID}-cert.pem
```

[END UPDATE]

Example code to generate a client certificate. Change CLIENT_ID and CLIENT_SERIAL for each certificate that you generate. ca.pem and ca.key are your CA certificate and private key.

```
CLIENT_ID="device-0001"
CLIENT_SERIAL=0001

openssl genrsa -aes256 -passout pass:xxxx -out ${CLIENT_ID}.pass.key 4096
openssl rsa -passin pass:xxxx -in ${CLIENT_ID}.pass.key -out ${CLIENT_ID}.key
rm ${CLIENT_ID}.pass.key

# generate the CSR
openssl req -new -key ${CLIENT_ID}.key -out ${CLIENT_ID}.csr

# issue this certificate, signed by the CA (ca.pem ca.key)
openssl x509 -req -days 375 -in ${CLIENT_ID}.csr -CA ca.pem -CAkey ca.key -set_serial ${CLIENT_SERIAL} -out ${CLIENT_ID}.pem

# Give the client the file: ${CLIENT_ID}.full.pem
cat ${CLIENT_ID}.key ${CLIENT_ID}.pem ca.pem > ${CLIENT_ID}.full.pem
```

Comment: Sorry... I mean using ACM. I have created using `openssl`

Comment: Using ACM, there is no CSR required for privte certs

Comment: Are you using ACM or ACM PCA? I updated my answer for AWS  ACM PCA which does use CSRs.

Comment: @overexchange - You cannot use AWS ACM for private certificates. ACM only supports Google managed services. To issue your own certificates, you must use AMC PCA.

Comment: yes we are using ACM PCA and then create own certificates for device, client and server.

Comment: Does ACMgr support SCEP protocol?

Comment: We use golang sdk but not domain specific language like aws cli

Comment: @overexchange - when you have a new question, create a new question. This question has been answered.

Comment: New question added: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56706023/does-aws-cert-manager-support-scep-protocol

Comment: @overexchange - for your new question, I do not know the answer. Hopefully, someone will know.

Comment: Any idea about multi region support? https://stackoverflow.com/q/56701903/3317808